# How do i fix pylance Import "pygame" could not be resolved reportmissingmodules. This issue is given for every non-builtin modules i import

Tags: python, module

I was making a program with a few non built-in modules. Each time I import a non built-in module it gives me this error: Import "pygame" could not be resolved reportmissingmodules(It does not work with any non built-in modules). I have tried installing latest version of vs code and python. I even changed the interpreter from python 3.11 to 3.12.1 I then restarted my PC and Vs Code. Even that does not work.

I then used Vs Code's python interpreter, it works but its buggy and really laggy! How can I fix this?

I have tried installing latest version of vs code and python. I even changed the interpreter from python 3.11 to 3.12.1 I even restarted my PC and Vs Code. Even that does not work.
[Look at the code with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Wzp.png) and with interpreters [Interpreters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdxiz.png)

Comment: How are you installing those modules? You are installing them, right?

Answer (score -1):

The error shows you that the modules `pygame` and `playsound` is not installed.

You can install the modules with [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/), a command-line site package installer for python.

For example if you want to install `pygame` in your computer, you can type in the following command to install it:

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

You can do the same for `playsound`.

Then make sure the installed packages are stored under the directories that `import` search for, for example the `(path-to-python-directory)/Lib/site-packages` directory.

Comment: I have already installed pygame and playsound

Comment: @Ben Sometimes the `import` cannot find the installed packages. Make sure the installed files are on the `(Python Appdata Directory)\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pygame`.